# `sjPlot::tab_model()` summary statistics reordering and splitting of R-squared and R-squared-adjusted

Tags: r, sjplot

I'm using `sjPlot::tab_model()` to create output tables of regressions. (Reproducible example below).

Two quick questions about summary statistics below a table:

1. Is there some way that I can report `R^2` and `R^2 adjusted` on **separate** lines?
2. How can I reorder summary statistics such as `$R^2$`, `AIC`, etc?

```
library("sjPlot")

lm1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)
lm2 <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)
lm3 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp, mtcars)


tab_model(lm1, lm2, lm3,
          show.ci = 0,
          show.aic = 1,
          show.loglik = 1,
          show.fstat = 1,
          show.r2 = 1)
```

This is the actual output I'm currently getting:

[image]

This is my desired output:[image]