# regression output tables with standard errors in a new column, with "Latex look" html output

Tags: r, stargazer, texreg

When displaying tables of regressions (say with `stargazer` or `texreg::htmlreg`), is there a way where I can:

1. Make the standard errors be displayed in a new, separate column next to the coefficient estimates?
2. Have the output in html, while having the look of Latex produced tables (both `stargazer` and `texreg::htmlreg` do this, often referred to as "publication ready").

Desired output format:
[image]

I've tried using:

- `single.row = TRUE` but that puts the standard errors into the same cell, not a new column.

Reproducible example below:

```
library(texreg)
library(stargazer)

mtcars
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
m2 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + wt, data = mtcars)

htmlreg(list(m1, m2), file = "htmlreg_table.html", single.row = 1)
stargazer(m1, m2, out = "stargazer_table.html", single.row = TRUE)
```

As you can see, the output looks "publication ready", but the standard errors are in the same column, rather than in a new separate column.

I'm open to using any package, not only `stargazer` or `texreg`, which is why this question differs from:
[report regression result using stargazer to add separate column for standard error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52172469/report-regression-result-using-stargazer-to-add-separate-column-for-standard-err)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think `sjPlot::tab_model()` does a lot of what you want:

```
library(sjPlot)

tab_model(m1, m2, show.se = TRUE,
          dv.labels = c("Model 1", "Model 2"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That's a great solution. You wouldn't know how I could separate the R^2 and R^2 adjusted, onto two separate lines, would you? I asked before, but haven't found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57505167/sjplottab-model-summary-statistics-reordering-and-splitting-of-r-squared-a

Comment: No way that I know of, `tab_model` has a lot of options but once you exhaust them I think there's not much you can do to change the layout.